# How to place a component at the end of the line of a text

Tags: react-native

I want to put a component at the end of a multi-line text. Having the text and the component wrapped in a view and setting its flex-direction to row doesn't help.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: multiline text with component]

Here is the code

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
<Text>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</Text>
<Component />
</View>
```

Component Code:

```
<View style={{width: width, borderRadius: width/2}}>
<Text>{children}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: it's something else, it's a circle with a text comprised of text wrapped in a view (for styling)

Comment: It's as simple as `<View style={{width: width, borderRadius: width/2}}><Text>{children}</Text></View>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot put a `<View>` inside a `<Text>` Component, but I have a workaround for you which uses `react-native-svg`. Of course this is just a demo and you probably have to adjust/fine tune it.

You can install `react-native-svg` with:

```
npm install --save react-native-svg
```

**Component Code:**

```
import Svg, { Circle } from 'react-native-svg'; 
...
const TestComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Svg height="35" width="100">
      <Circle cx="15" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue" />
      <Svg.Text x="25" y="25" fill="#000" fontSize="15" textAnchor="middle" fontWeight="bold" > 
        {children}
      </Svg.Text>
      <Svg.Text x="75" y="25" fill="#000" fontSize="15" textAnchor="middle" fontWeight="bold" >
       {children}
      </Svg.Text>
    </Svg>
  );
}
```

**Example:**

[image: demo]

**Working Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/rJZlZBX2V

Edit: 
This workaround works only on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I got `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`.

I presumed the error was caused from `Svg.Text` (couldn't find in react-native-svg about that), but when I deleted it leaving only `<Circle cx="15" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue" />` within the `Svg` I got `Unexpected view type nested under text node`

Also, I cannot run your Demo on my expo client and on snack

Comment: I notice it's only runnable on iOS

Comment: @user1677104 This is only a workaround for iOS. On android it‘s impossible to do!

Comment: @user1677104 I would still apreciate an upvote and marking it as accepted answer. I put a lot of work in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    <Text style={{ color: "#757575", lineHeight: 23 }}>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                        {" "}
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                            <Image
                                style={{ height: 18, width: 18 }}
                                source={images.documentLoaded}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Text>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqi5s.png)